# Im getting HTTP ERROR 404 when i scaffold Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

Im getting the 404 error when i scaffold identity, when I delete the pages it creates the project works just fine.

Comment: 404 means the page is not found,you need to check if the route exists.

Comment: This is my route but i placed a debugpoint and the HomeController is never reached. app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
                       pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Comment: Can you share your route?Have you had area in your route?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/a9IgUfu This is the full path to the controller C:\Users\mariu\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Areas\Customer\Controllers\HomeController.cs

Answer (score 0):

In your CustomerController.cs after the namespace please add

```
[Area("Customer")]
```

if it doesn't work remove your Customer and again add it by right click on Areas, then add Area. In this new Area add a new controller (CustomerController) and related razor views.